What is the correct interpretation of the capacity formula with modulation?
Someone sent me the image below, and I think I'm confused as well.  Is the second formula (modulation) correct? What does it mean? From the symbol, I think it represents capacity, but it doesn't make much sense to me.
1. Shannon capacity:
$ C = B \log_{2}(1+\text{SNR}) \text{ bps} $
2. Modulation:
$ C = B \log_{2}(M) \log_{2}(1+\text{SNR}) $


since $(2) > (1)\quad\forall M>2$, and $(1)$ is an upper bound, $(2)$ must be incorrect, assuming it describes the same $C$.

Thanks. Can you guess what they could possibly mean by (2)?

no, not really. And it's not that sensible to try and interpret screenshots of blackboards without the accompanying lecture, so I'd really think it's better if I don't speculate there :)
